# UiCollectionView not select corret Cell when saving object Parse.com

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, parse-platform, uicollectionviewcell

sorry for the probably stupid question but I can not fix ... In my ViewController I have a collection view, and I'm trying to save the selection of the cell with a PFRelation. So far so good, but when I go to check on databrowser Parse I always recognizes only a selected cell where am I doing wrong? wrong is the way I implemented the NSIndexPath?

```
- (IBAction)FFPostSend:(id)sender {
    PFObject *FFSalvaPost = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [FFSalvaPost setValue:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"Utente"];
    [FFSalvaPost setValue:self.TextView.text forKey:@"Testo"];
    UIImage *image = [self FF_RifimensionaImmagine:self.FF_image ToWidth:(440.0f) andHeight:(500.0f)];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    PFFile *oggettoFoto =[PFFile fileWithName:@"Immagine.png" data:imageData];
    [FFSalvaPost setObject:oggettoFoto forKey:@"Immagine"];
    PFRelation *relation = [FFSalvaPost relationforKey:@"Scelti"];



    if (FFSwitch.on) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;

        [self.FFCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];

        if ([[self.FFCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] isSelected]) {

            NSLog(@"selected count %i",[self.FFCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems].count);

            PFObject *UserSelezionati = [[self.ArrayForUserFoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"Da_User"];

            [FFSalvaPost setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"FLASH_PUSH"];



            [relation addObject:UserSelezionati];
        }


    } else {
        [FFSalvaPost setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"FLASH_PUSH"];

    }

    PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [acl setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    [FFSalvaPost setACL:acl];

    [FFSalvaPost saveInBackground];

    [self performSelector:@selector(FFConfermaPost) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at only the first row:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;
```

You could use [UICollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForSelectedItems) to get NSIndexPaths for the selected items and work on those.

Something like:

```
NSArray *indexes = [self.FFCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexes) {   
        PFObject *UserSelezionati = [[self.ArrayForUserFoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"Da_User"];
        [FFSalvaPost setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"FLASH_PUSH"];
        [relation addObject:UserSelezionati];
}
```

The code inside the loop is from your question, i didn't review or edit that.